# FirebaseAuthFallbackService memory leak

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, memory-leaks, firebase-authentication

I have some annoying memory leak, happens almost always when I am in app or out, i cant realize when

```
 ====================================
HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
====================================
1 APPLICATION LEAKS

References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.

1166 bytes retained by leaking objects
┬───
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.zza instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 1.7 kB in 10 objects
│    zza instance of com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService
│    ↓ zza.zza
│          ~~~
╰→ com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.
​     FirebaseAuthFallbackService received Service#onDestroy() callback)
​     Retaining 1.2 kB in 9 objects
​     key = 2d579c34-3b0a-4dee-a79c-a2eefe3a9933
​     watchDurationMillis = 5157
​     retainedDurationMillis = 143
​     mApplication instance of com.upgrades.venue.pro.MainApplication
​     mBase instance of android.app.ContextImpl
====================================
0 LIBRARY LEAKS

A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
====================================
0 UNREACHABLE OBJECTS

An unreachable object is still in memory but LeakCanary could not find a strong reference path
from GC roots.
====================================
METADATA

Please include this in bug reports and Stack Overflow questions.

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 29
Build.MANUFACTURER: Google
LeakCanary version: 2.6
App process name: com.upgrades.venue.pro
```

I am using firebase auth in repository via `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`

Instance zza.zza leaks constantly
I need ur help, thanks

Comment: I am also having this issue.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this case?

Comment: I did not, and question is closed a long time now

Comment: No one even answering the issue in Github as well regarding this

Comment: I am facing the same issue as well, any fixes?

Comment: Its firebase bug. Still they didn't fix it. 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2387 

I voted to re-open this question